# why can't I add DejaVu font to fpdf in PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to fpdf and python, so I'm sure this is probably something very simple, but I can't seem to add a utf-8 compatible font, in this case DejaVu. I have placed the font folder downloaded together with FPDF in just about every other folder on my mac running OS 10.15.7. I'm using PyCharm 2020.3 with python 3.9.

I get the following output:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.9 /Users/brc/Documents/Python/AvenidasPython/FontTest.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/brc/Documents/Python/AvenidasPython/FontTest.py", line 5, in <module>
pdf.add_font('DejaVu', '', 'DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf', uni=True)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 577, in add_font
if (Path(parent) / fname).exists():
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1071, in __new__
    self = cls._from_parts(args, init=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 696, in _from_parts
    drv, root, parts = self._parse_args(args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 680, in _parse_args
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Originally the issue appeared in a more complex script, but I get the same error from the simplest of scripts:

```
    from fpdf import FPDF

    pdf = FPDF('L', 'mm', 'A4')
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.add_font('DejaVu', '', 'DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf', uni=True)
```

It seems to me that this is something linear so I didn't bother contextualizing why I need this to work, but I can do so if required. Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try `/full/path/to/font.ttf` ? Did you try to put in folder with code/script?

Comment: if you have font in folder with code/script then you may need `HOME = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` to get full path to folder with code and use it to create full path to font `os.path.join(HOME, "DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf")` in this folder,.

Comment: @furas yes i tried with the full path but to no avail. Right now I'm on a different mac, but oddly enough with the same files on the same locations (iCloud drive), it works... Monday I'll try what you proposed on your second comment with my other computer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding @furas suggestion to the file name:

```
 os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/font/', "DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf")
```

For it to work across different computers I had to first check if the .pkl files existed and if so delete them as they're hard-coded with the .ttf directory (if I understood correctly). For that I used:

```
 for font in fonts:
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/" + font)):
            os.remove(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/" + font))
```

where fonts contains the names of the files created when adding fonts to FPDF